# How to change the font of the page numbers in word using delphi xe5

Tags: delphi, fonts, ms-word

I am automating word documents. Generating them solely from code.

Currently i am adding a page number in the header of each page, But i would like to know how to change the font name of the page number along with the font size.

Any help would be appreciated.

Please note, wrddoc is the active document variable.

here is the code i create the page number with:
`wrdDoc.Sections[1].Headers[1].PageNumbers.Add(wdAlignPageNumberRight);`

And i tried the following code to change the font but i get an error, "method font is not a supported automation object":

```
wrdDoc.Sections[1].Headers[1].PageNumbers.Font.name:='Times New Roman';
wrdDoc.Sections[1].Headers[1].PageNumbers.Font.Size:=12;
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me:

```
wrdDoc.Sections.First.Headers.Item(1).Range.Font.Name := 'Times New Roman';
wrdDoc.Sections.First.Headers.Item(1).Range.Font.Size:= 12;
```

Delphi XE, Office 2010.